# How to ensure the existence of user before deleting from local user group?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to Replace a user in local group using powershell script.

```
Function ReplaceUserInGroup {

    Param (
        [string]$Group,
        [string]$OldUserName,
        [string]$NewUserName        
    )

    [string]$computer=$env:ComputerName


    If($Group -And $OldUserName -And $NewUserName ) {
        $LocalGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$Group,group"

        $LocalGroup.Add("WinNT://$computer/$NewUserName")

        $LocalGroup.Remove("WinNT://$OldUserName")
    }
    Else {
            Write-Warning " ReplaceUserInGroup : Some or all the parameters are empty"
    }


}
```

The problem with this script is ,it will fail if the OldUserName doesn't exist in the local group.

I would like to check whether the user exists in the group before removing the user from localgroup.

In other words I would like to wrap Remove function line in some if condition like belows.

```
If (UserName exists in Localgroup) {
    $LocalGroup.Remove("WinNT://$OldUserName")
}
```

How to check the user existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $members = $LocalGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members") | Foreach-Object  {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null) }

    if($members -contains $OldUserName)
    {
        "$OldUserName is member"
    }
    else
    {
        "$OldUserName is NOT a member"
    }
```

Comment: If i use contains even if it match partial it will throw $OldUserName is member , isn't it?. I think it is better to looping through $members. Foreach ($member in $members ) { if($member -eq $OldUserName)
    {
        "$OldUserName is member"
    }
    else
    {
        "$OldUserName is NOT a member"
    }

Comment: It's the same as using -contains and is less efficient. If you want to check for partial match replace -contains with -like and use a wildcard expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $objOu = [ADSI]"WinNT://${env:Computername}"
    $localUsers = $objOu.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}  | % {$_.name[0].ToString()}

    # Ensure we have local user BOB
    if($localusers -contains "BOB" ){
       Write-Host "local user ${env:Computername}/BOB already exists"
    }
    else{
       Write-Host "Creating local user: /BOB"
       NET USER BOB "qwefgnbm" /ADD
    }
```

This checks if a user exists and adds one if it is not present. It may be of use.